# Excel 2016 insert new table row to LAST ROW messes up formula

Tags: excel

I have a column in a table that will show the current balance of each row:

```
=SUBTOTAL(109,$O$7:P137)
```

When I insert a new row ANYWHERE in the table, (via right-clicking and choosing "insert table row above\bellow) the formulas update perfectly on all other rows.

Only when I right click the LAST ROW and select "insert table row bellow," the formula of the row above the newly inserted row gets messed up.

What's weird is that the NEW row actually DOES have the correct formula. It's just the row above the new one that takes on the LAST row's formula instead of keeping a sequential sequence of the numbers.

Also, notice that the row above the new one - its FORMAT also gets messed up which I'd like to know why as well.

[image: BEFORE ADDING NEW ROW]

[image: AFTER ADDING NEW ROW TO LAST]

Any ideas what the problem can be?

Comment: The table name is tbl_main and the header of column P is called "Balance"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the column headers of your table to set a reference.

Try this

```
=SUBTOTAL(109,$O$7:[@Balance])
```